# Inverse Laplace transform with minus $\Delta$ in denominator

Tags: laplace-transform

Please help me find this inverse Laplace transform. 
$$
F(s)=\dfrac{2s-3}{s^{2}-2s+2}
$$
I couldn't resolve the denominator, because the quadratic  has discriminant  $\Delta=-4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the discriminant is negative, so there are no roots of the denominator. This means that instead of factoring it, you should complete the square: 
$$s^2-2s+2 = (s-1)^2+1$$
Then split the fraction as 
$$\frac{2(s-1)}{(s-1)^2+1}+ \frac{1}{(s-1)^2+1}$$
Consult the [table of Laplace transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms) and don't forget the [frequency shift property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems).